# Creating loop with urllib

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2')
filename, headers = opener.retrieve("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image", '/Users/barony/Desktop/Face Paint/Public/gettyimages-2637237.jpg')
```

I'm trying to make the URL request and save the picture every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
import urllib.request

while True:
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2')
    filename, headers = opener.retrieve("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image", '/Users/barony/Desktop/Face Paint/Public/gettyimages-2637237.jpg')

    time.sleep(5)
```